# SendKeys and Taking Photos of Screen

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I made this VB.NET code to take a picture of my entire screen, but instead it only takes a photo of the focused area. Why is this?

```
  Public Function SaveScreen(ByVal theFile As String) As Boolean

            Try
                SendKeys.Send("{PRTSC}")
                Application.DoEvents()

                Dim data As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()

                If data.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then
                    Dim bmp As Bitmap = CType(data.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), Bitmap)
                    bmp.Save(theFile, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                End If
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(0)      'save memory by removing the image from the clipboard
                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return False
            End Try

        End Function
```

Comment: See my answer on your previous question, which seems oddly similar.

Comment: @Jay, I don't know how to do that. I am barely capable at throwing this together.

Comment: No problem. Did you have problems looking at my example? I would personally shy away from sendkeys. I can elaborate on the other post.

Comment: This is annotated in the MSDN Library article for SendKeys.Send().  `{PRTSC} {reserved for future use}`.  Another way of saying "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

instead SendKeys, you can try the API-function keybd_event

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal bVk As Byte, _
ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

Private Const kbdDown = 0
Private Const kbdUp = 2



Private Sub SendKey(ByVal Key As Byte)
    Call keybd_event(Key, 0, kbdDown, 0)
    Call keybd_event(Key, 0, kbdUp, 0)

End Sub
```

The Key-Code of Print-Key is 42 (0x2A)